# How do I add code to the Snippets Library?

Tags: xcode10

The revise snippet access doesn't allow for persistent view and hence, I'm unable to snide selected code into the library.  Nor able to to a cut/paste.

What's the alternative means?

... or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I also was unable to find that and found out after sometime, you can see my answer for alternatives in:

[Adding code snippet in Code Snippet Library (Xcode 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240838/adding-code-snippet-in-code-snippet-library-xcode-10?answertab=active#tab-top)