# Adding code snippet in Code Snippet Library (Xcode 10)

Tags: xcode, code-snippets, xcode10

Recently when I was using **Xcode 10 beta 3**, I tried to **make a code snippet and add it to the code snippet library**.

But the **drag drop cannot be done as the code snippet library is detached in Xcode 10**, and hides when I click on a code.

How to add code snippet in code snippet library in Xcode 10?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

After some time found out.

`Select the code` you want to add to library. Right-click on it and click on `Create Code Snippet` from the pop-up menu.

Apparently upto Xcode 9.x.x, this option was not there.

[image]

Comment: To edit snippet open snippet bar (curly braces button), click once on snippet and wait a bit.

Comment: @Sugar perfect, tnx

Comment: Just in case. To add a placeholder to code snippet, 
add  <# some_placeholder #> text.

Answer (score 6):

For Xcode 10 to make a Snippet,

1) Select the resign of code you want to reuse in future.

2) Click the right button.

3) In the context menu, select "Create Code Snippet". The Snippet Library will appear with a new snippet created.

Answer (score 5):

to create a snippet you can do it in the following way:

1. menu editor and select **Create Code Snippet**:

[image: Create Code Snippet]

2. In the box that appears, fill all the information of your snippet:
   [image]

if you want your variables to be highlighted in gray you have to surround the variable in the following way, <# name #>:

example:

```
public let <#name#>: <#type#>
```